# c++ move semantics : when are they required to be explicit?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, move-semantics

Considering for example:

```
class A
{

 public: 
 A(int v)
 {
    a_[0]=v;
    a_[1]=v;
 }  

 A(A&& other) noexcept
 : a_(std::move(other.a_)){}

 A& operator=(A&& other) noexcept
 {
   a_ = std::move(other.a_);
   return *this;
 }

 private:
 std::array<int,2> a_;

};
```

the code corresponding to the move semantics could be considered "obvious" (i.e. moving all the members that are moveable).
If it is omitted, do compilers still manage to generate binaries that will move instances of A in a proper way ?

Comment: Yes, this is true for both move and copy.

Comment: Is this basically a question asking whether compiler is able to automatically generate move constructors?

Comment: In this particular example, there are no move-able member variables.  A default (compiler synthesized) move constructor will do the right thing, and copy the member variable.